# Помогите разобраться с StackTraceElement[]

Tags: java, stacktrace

Доброго времени суток. Помогите понять суть StackTrace.

В учебном материале даётся объяснение

> Java-машина ведет запись всех вызовов функций. У нее есть для этого специальная коллекция – стек. Когда одна функция вызывает другую, Java-машина помещает в этот стек новый элемент StackTraceElement. Когда функция завершается этот элемент удаляется из стека. Таким образом, в этом стеке всегда хранится актуальная информация о текущем состоянии «стека вызовов функций»

Далее приводится пример

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    method1();
  }

  public static void method1()
  {
    method2();
  }

  public static void method2()
  {
    method3();
  }

  public static void method3()
  {
    StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
    for (StackTraceElement element : stackTraceElements)
    {
       System.out.println(element.getMethodName());
    }
  }
```

В результате выполнения которого мы получаем

```
getStackTrace
method3
method2
method1
main
```

Если я правильно все понимаю, то конструкция

```
StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
```

работает следующим образом:

```
//Cоздаём переменную типа StackTraceElement[]
StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements 

//Присваеваем ей ссылку на текущий поток и заносим в массив специальные элементы StackTrace
Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()
```

Вопрос №1: каким образом в этом массиве `StackTraceElement[]` вся информация о вызываемых методах, если сказано, что после выполнения метода информация из стека удаляется?

Вопрос №2: В одном из заданий просят вернуть имя метода, который его вызывает

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    method1();
}

public static String method1()
{
    method2();
    return Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getMethodName();


}

public static String method2()
{
    method3();
    return Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getMethodName();
}

public static String method3()
{
    method4();
    return Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getMethodName();
}

public static String method4()
{
    method5();
    return Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getMethodName();
}

public static String method5()
{
    return Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getMethodName();
}
```

Каким образом работает конструкция

```
return Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getMethodName();
```

если мы не создавали `StackTraceElement[]`. Значит ли это, что он неявно создается JVM при выполнении программы?

Comment: *если мы не создавали StackTraceElement[]* - он вообще никогда не создается на пользовательской стороне, его всегда предоставляет JVM

Comment: Понятно. А что по первому вопросу?

Comment: Ну, строго говоря, StackTraceElement - это не ссылка на стек, это его предсталвение в определенный момент времени, поэтому нет никаких проблем "подержать" его у себя и выпустить в другом месте (все будет немного по-другому в новом апи, которое будет добавлено в следующей джаве, но это отдельная тема). Но конкретно в данных примерах он нигде не держится и используется ровно в тех местах, о которых должен дать ответ, *во время выполнения метода*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Вопрос №1: каким образом в этом массиве `StackTraceElement[]` вся информация о вызываемых методах, если сказано, что после выполнения метода информация из стека удаляется?

Вы вызываете метод `getStackTrace()` в методе `method3()`. На момент вызова `getStackTrace()` метод `method3()` еще **не завершился**, следовательно, метод `getStackTrace()` возвратит всю цепочку вызовов вплоть до вызова метода `getStackTrace()`.

Если, например, Вы вызовете `getStackTrace()` в методе `main(...)` **после** вызова метода `method1()`, то получите следующий вывод:

```
getStackTrace
main
```

Вы не видите тут методов `method1()` и прочих – записи об их вызовах были удалены, так как на момент вызова метода `getStackTrace()` метод `method1()` **был завершен**.

> Вопрос №2: В одном из заданий просят вернуть имя метода, который его вызывает
>
> ...
>
> Каким образом работает конструкция
>
> ```
> return Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getMethodName();
> ```
>
> если мы не создавали StackTraceElement[]. Значит ли это, что он неявно создается JVM при выполнении программы?

Да, значит. Элементы в стек вызовов добавляет сама JVM.

На вершине стека находится запись о вызове самого метода `getStackTrace()`, за ним следует запись об имени метода, непосредственно в котором был вызван метод `getStackTrace()`, в элементе `getStackTrace()[i]` (`i>0`) находится имя метода, который вызвал метод, который находится в `getStackTrace()[i-1]`.

Comment: Вот оно что. Значит если бы я просто написал 5 методов и не вызывал их друг-в-друге и то и элемент в массиве было бы всего два - getStackTrace и имя метода в котором  его вызвал?

Comment: @РоманDriveMind, Да, верно.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь все стало ясно

Answer (score 2):

Только не понятно, почему вы возвращаете [2] элемент. В вашем задании нужно вернуть имя метода, который его вызывает.

```
public static String method5() {
    return Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()**[2]**.getMethodName(); }
```

В данном случае его вызовет текущий метод 5. Длину стека можно проверить вызовам метод length:
`Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace().length` - кол-во записанных методов в Стэк, в данном случае будет 7 записей. Последним элементом будет сам метод `getStacktrace()`. Нам нужно вернуть метод, который его вызывает, значит нужно вернуть i-1-1(5) (нумерация элементов в массиве java начинается с индекса '0').
В итоге получим:

```
return Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[5].getMethodName();
```

Для метода 4 будет

```
return Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[4].getMethodName();
```

А вот если вы хотите вывести номер строки, вызвавший этот метод, тогда да,
`return Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getLineNumber()` вернет номер строки метода 4, который вызвал метод 5.

Answer (score 2):

Ответ выше немного неточен. В стеке всегда метод вызвавший `StackTrace`, будет на позиции[2].

- 0 - getStackTrace
- 1 - имя метода (свое имя)
- 2 - имя метода кто вызвал [1]
- 3 - имя метода кто вызвал [2]
- 4 - и т.д.

Мы тут видим прошлое, что происходило до запуска текущего методa.

Comment: Поясните, а где неточность? Там тоже самое, только другими словами.

Comment: @BeardedBeaver Ваша правка убирает не только лишнее, но и знак пунктуации.  Сообщение написано "народным языком", но если вы правите, то привидите его также в соответствие с нормами русского языка.